# C - Display a string of character with a low Macros

Tags: c, string, macros

I need you for a little problem.
I try to read a file and display his contents (like the fonction "cat") in terms of the value of my Macro.
With my BUFF_SIZE 4096 I display the string easy, but when I put BUFF_SIZE 1, my program display the first char of all lines.
I'm not sure at 100% about my code cause I'm on my personal computer, but if you really need it I can give you it tomorrow.
For my problem I think I must do something like the function strdup, but I dont really know how can I include it on my code

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 4096

char     *my_function(const int a)
{
 static int i;
 static char **str;
 static int ret;
 static char *buff[BUFF_SIZE];
 static int j;

 i = 0;
 j = 0;
 str = malloc(BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
 while ((ret =read(a, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
  {
    while (buff[i] != '\0')
      {
        str[j] = buff[i];
        i++;
        j++;
      }
    return (str);
  }
free(str);
}
```

Sorry for my approximate english

Comment: (a, buff, BUFF_SIZE) will return an int? how so?

Comment: `str = malloc(BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(char));` does not allocate enough memory; use `str = malloc(BUFF_SIZE * sizeof str[0]);`

Comment: I forgot to change the read, i have edit my message it's ret = read(a,buff,BUFF_SIZE)

Comment: And.... ufff... there's something terribly wrong with this code: why a return inside the inner loop? With it, you will only read the file once. Then, you exit the function.

Comment: The `read()` system call does not null terminate the input data. Your loop needs to cycle over the number of characters that were read.  But you need to lose all those static variables, too, and work out what the real purpose of the function is (because it surely doesn't do what is intended -- it leaks horribly, at best).  If you want to slurp an entire file into memory ('slurp' is the technical term for reading a whole file). you normally find the size of the file (`lseek()`, for example), allocate the memory, and read.  Or you incrementally allocate memory in blocks of say 64 KiB.  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static char *buff[BUFF_SIZE];`

You have declared buff as an array of pointers to char. At the same time the way you use it suggests that what you really meant is

`static char buff[BUFF_SIZE];`

Your function will also have serious issues if you call it more than once.
For instance, `i` and `j` are probably not going to be zero on the next call to my_function(). 'static' means that variable will be zero-initialized when the program starts. It does not zero-init variables on function entry.

Comment: And str should be defined as `char *str`, not `char **str`

Comment: Indeed. `gcc -Wall -Werror` should be default compiler settings. :-)